# Windows 10 auto update content while app running

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10

I have a windows 10 app which communicates with api to get all the content. It does so when it starts which is good. I want the app to update when the app is running automatically whenever there is new content to download from api. I have implemented the update with click of a button which runs get api calls to update app which I know is not a good way of doing it.

I just need suggestion of how to achieve this kind of functionality in Windows 10 App so that it automatically runs the update function maybe every 15 minutes or whenever there is new content.

Comment: how do you expect the app to intuit that there is new content available?

Answer (score 0):

You need a BackgroundTask. You can define one in your AppxManifest.xml which runs under various conditions, e.g. in your case, a timer. The OS will fire that off as appropriate. That can check if there's new data in a reliable way. [Your app may be suspended so any timer in your app won't reliably fire. You're really looking for background processing - check for data updates. BackgroundTasks are designed for exactly that scenario.]

Then, if you app is running, you need to communicate with your app. Whether the backgroundtask downloads the data and 'pings' your app, or the backgroundtask pings your app to download the data is a minor detail; the backgroundtask knows there's data available, and if your app's running you want to tell it. One way to do this is via AppServices

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.appservice.aspx

Answer (score -2):

One simple and easy idea could be the use of the DispatcherTimer-Class. A timer that runs every x Minutes/Seconds and checks for new data on your API. When new data is available, update your data source which is binded to your UI-Elements.

More Information on the DispatcherTimer:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx

Comment: What was wrong with this answer, maybe I can help more?

Comment: The app may get suspended, so a timer in your app may never fire. The right answer is a BackgroundTask